# How to count the number of database(model) enteries with a filter corresponding to an entry in own model field?

Tags: django-models, django-views

I have a "jobs" model having 'company' field. I need to count the number of jobs for a company of my choice and display in my template. 
I could possibly do -

```
job_count = Job.objects.filter(company='Google').count()
```

This is working also.
But I am printing this value to my current model template which also has a field called 'company_name'. Basically I want to print the number of jobs for every company I have in this template. I can have Google , Amazon etc..

The above code will show me the count of jobs only for Google.
I want to avoid hardcoding.

How do I write it?

I tried this--

```
job_count = Job.objects.filter(company='{{ currentmodel.company_name }}').count()
```

I want something as-

```
job_count = Job.objects.filter(company='this.company_name').count()
```

(this) corresponds to my current Company( Google, Amazon) ..

This syntax is wrong I know , how do I correct this?

Expected results---

Google - 2,
Amazon - 4 
(whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a query that counts the number of `Job`s *per* `company`, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

job_counts = Job.objects.values('company').annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('company')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, like:

```
<QuerySet [
    { 'company': 'Amazon', 'count': 25},
    { 'company': 'Google', 'count': 14},
    { 'company': 'Qux', 'count': 2}
]>
```

You however should consider remodeling, and make a `Company` model and link `Job`s to a company through a `ForeignKey`. This will make querying more convenient as well, since you can then simply annotate your `Company`s with the number of `Job`s.

If you make a `ForeignKey` to the `Company`, like:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then you can simply query with:

```
companies = Company.objects.annotate(njobs=Count('job'))
```

Now the `Company` objects that arise from this, will have an extra attribute `njobs` with the number of `Job`s, like:

```
,code>{% for company in companies %}
    <tr><td>{{ company.company_id }}</td><td>{{ company.njobs }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How do I print it in my templates? Currently I'm passing it as a context and simply doing {{ job_counts }} .. But I'm getting this printed --

```<QuerySet [{'company': 'Amazon', 'count': 1}, {'company': 'Google', 'count': 1}]>
```

Comment: A already have a company model, I can surely consider remodelling If I don't get this way. Else this method looks peaceful. Bt just tell me how to print this?

Comment: @AmanBhatnagar: you iterate over it, like `{% for item in job_counts %} {{ item.company }}: {{ job.count }}{% endfor %}`.

Comment: I'm actually printing it in the form of a table --

```<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company ID</th>
        <th>Jobs number</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 {% for company in companies %}
<tr>
        <td>{{ company.company_id }}</td>
        <td>"""Job Count here"""</td>
```

Comment: @AmanBhatnagar: that is thus *the* reason to use a `ForeignKey` instead, since then you can annotate the `companies` queryset to have an extra attribute named count. By not doing so, you introduce data duplication (which is a severe anti-pattern on its own), and your database is not normalized: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization Finally it would result in the *N+1* query problem by making individual queries.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks! How do I make the field then?

```count = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)```

How to use this now in views.py? Can you alter your above code?

Comment: @AmanBhatnagar: no, you just add a `ForeignKey` from the `Job` to the `Company` to specify for what company the job is, then you can annotate your `Company`s with the number of jobs, see edit.

Comment: ```job_count = Company.objects.annotate(njobs=Count('job'))```

So I did this and passed job_count as a context again. Did {{ job_count }} in the template. Still I get this --

```<QuerySet [<Company: Google>, <Company: Amazon>]>```

Doesn't even show the count

Comment: @AmanBhatnagar: you do *not* need `job_count` here. You use `companies = Company.objects.annotate(..)`, and then you can render `{{ company.njobs }}`.

Comment: Can you answer this please? 

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534404/how-to-add-search-bar-for-django-template)